dynamic vanilla event catching: what is wrong with this code
Why does this code do not works?
in theory it seems to do instead... but no.


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  let appendix_wrap = document.getElementById("wrap");
  let hafigli_liv2 = appendix_wrap.querySelectorAll('ul.ul-submenu');
  hafigli_liv2.forEach(ul_li_liv2 => {
    ul_li_liv2.addEventListener("click", (lk_liv2) => {
      const link_liv2 = lk_liv2.target.matches('ul.ul-submenu li.menu-item-has-children a');
      this.preventDefault(); //evita che cambi pagina
    });
  });
});
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>prova js</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>js menu flush</h1>
  <ul id="wrap">
    <li id="menu-item-658" class="menu-item-has-children ul-submenu-li">
      <a title="tre" href="#">tre</a>
      <ul class="submenu-submenu">
        <li id="menu-item-663" class="menu-item-has-children">
          <a title="due" href="#">due</a>
          <ul class="ul-submenu">
            <li id="menu-item-664" class="menu-item-664">
              <a title="uno" href="#">uno</a>
          </ul>
      </ul>
      </li>
  </ul>
</body>
<p class="menu-item-description">Le maniglie perfette</p>
</li>
</body>

</html>



The logic is that i click in A element inside some UL and LIs and ULs and LIs and it has to not open the link.
Please help

Please post a [mcve] including the relevant HTML. You can use a Stack Snippet to make it executable.

Why not put the event listener on the A elements?

the problem seems to be that the code will reproduced only once, without "target" and never with its use. So potentially not change situation if i change to which element i put the listener. but thank you, i appreciate the try.

Are the elements created dynamically?

yes the problem is that they are dynamic elements as in title

Use .matches() instead of .closest(). closest() matches containing elements, not the element itself.

tried, nothing change the effects

this.preventDefault() should be lk_liv2.preventDefault(). this is the target, but preventDefault() is an Event method. You should have gotten an error in the console for that.

please may you explain? i've tried with link_liv2 too instead of 'this' that in theory is the right constant to execute event, or no? why i shouldn't get and event on my target with that constant or "this"?
what i am triying to say is that it works if i use lk_liv2 but it make useless the creation of the constant?!

When an event listener is called, the argument is the Event, this is equivalent to event.currentTarget.
